# Lock for specific threads in java

Tags: java, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to implement a tic tac toe game based on server and client in java.

For each two clients connecting to the server I want to create a new game which will not be correlated to another game.

The thing is, I'm using lock and unlock mechanism which does interfere with the others clients game.

So my question is, is there a way to create a lock which will work on every 2 clients?

For every 2 clients I create a new lock.

Thanks.

Comment: I suspect you'll have to create your own. You could pass a token between players meaning that only the player with the token can make a move and basically write your game model to support this concept

Comment: That sounds like a trivial requirement: every Java object can be used as a lock. Just have a unique object for each client.

Comment: Marko Topolnik means "for each game", since you want the two clients to share the lock.

Comment: If you're using a client-server pattern then you don't need locks, since the server is the only thing modifying the board.  If a client sends in a move and it's not the client's turn then the server simply discards the move.

Comment: When I think about it, I do have unique lock for each two clients. I've created a class with game details for each two players (Lock, board, details on the players and such...). Maybe it's not the problem but I can still see that the game is not working right, When I start one game, the other one get stucked and it is hard to debug this things...

Comment: You should have a single structure that holds the board, whose turn it is, and so on. That structure should have the lock that each player acquires to manipulate the game state.

Comment: Zim-Zam O'Pootertoot I used the lock to create some conditions, the first one for the other player to connect  and the second one for the other player turn, I use await and signal.

Comment: David Schwartz That is kind of what I did.

Comment: You can simplify things considerably by doing away with all shared mutable data structures, except for a few `BlockingQueues`.  For example, the server contains a `BlockingQueue` for moves, and each client contains a `BlockingQueue` for turn signals.  Client1 sends its move to the server's `BlockingQueue` and calls `take` on its own `BlockingQueue`, the server processes the move and sends a signal to Client2's `BlockingQueue`, Client2 sends its move to the server and calls `take` on its `BlockingQueue`, the server processes the move and sends a signal to Client1's `BlockingQueue`, etc

Comment: I don't want to change the entire project, it's already works for 2 players, I need to make it work for multiple games.

Comment: show some (simplified) code, e.g. your use of the lock in the "game" object.